# Javascript create regex for filter?

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving an object like this from the front-end app:

```
{
 name: "Red boys"
 category: "Fashion"
 subCategory: [
   { name: "sub"},
   { name: "Hub"}
   { name: "Mub"}
   // Here it is not static, Here can more or less object in the array
 ]
}
```

I have to create a new object from it:

```
{ category: {name: "Fashion", subCategory: {name: {$in: ["sub", "Hub", "Mub"]}}}}
```

Here is My Code-

```
let args = {};
for (let key in filters) {
    if (filters[key].length > 0) {
        if (key === "category") {
            args["category"] = {
                name: filters['category'],
                // Here I have to check if subCatgory has some value, then create subcategory field
                subCategory: {
                    name: {
                        $in: [] // Here I can't what I have to wrie
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(args);
```

Pleae help me. I can't understand this functionality. I search but I can get any solutions.

Comment: That whole object coming from Frontend application. I am writing backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the original object, and then restructure the properties from it into a new object. For the sub categories you can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array to create an array of objects.

```js
const fe = {
 name: 'Red boys',
 category: 'Fashion',
 subCategory: [
   { name: 'sub' },
   { name: 'Hub' },
   { name: 'Mub' }
 ]
};

// Get the category and subcategory from the
// object passed from the front-end app
const { category, subCategory } = fe;

// And create a new object
const be = {
  category: {
    name: 'Fashion',
    subCategory: {
      name: {
        $in: subCategory.map(s => s.name)
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(be);
```

Comment: I want this - `{ category: {name: "Fashion", subCategory: {name: {$in: ["sub", "Hub", "Mub"]}}}}`

Comment: Oops, I got it backwards. My updated answer should help. @Savana.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution to the objective:

```
out.subCategory.name['$in'] = in.subCategory.map( item => item.name );
```

```js
const inputData = {
 name: "Red boys",
 category: "Fashion",
 subCategory: [
   { name: "sub"},
   { name: "Hub"},
   { name: "Mub"}
 ]
};

function convertToDesired ( obj ) {
  const output = {
    category: {
      name: obj.category,
      subCategory: {
        name: {
          $in: obj.subCategory.map( item => item.name )
        }
      }
    }
  };
  return output;
}

console.log(convertToDesired(inputData))
```

Comment: Can you, do it with my writing way. From example code 

Comment: @Savana your code won't generate the desired output cause of that extra if statement but any way here is your version --> `$in: filters['subCategory'].map( item => item.name )`

Comment: But can I check if has subCategory?

Comment: @Savana you can check it by length of the subcatgeory array instead of If

Comment: How I can? Please describe

Comment: @Savana the code snippet you provided to generate the mongo query is really hard to read and you won't have easy time maintaining it in the future, i suggest you to take the simple approach and Repeat Yourself, until you feel the necessity of looping through object keys. why you insist on the looping by the way?

Comment: Right. I can create two separate filed. One for is category and then other one for is subCategory. Right?

Comment: @Savana yeah, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Answer (score -1):

@Suvana
Based on your implementation here is how you can achieve the desired output.
I attached the fiddle code as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/xco7vkn8/1/

```
for (let key in filters) {
      if (filters[key].length > 0) {
    if (key === "category") {
        args["category"] = {
            name: filters['category'],
            subcategory:{},
        }
    }
    else if(key ==="subCategory"){
        if(filters['subCategory'].length>0){
              new_array = [];

         filters['subCategory'].forEach(function (item, index) {
                    new_array.push(item.name);          
                    });
            args["category"].subcategory={
            name:{
                $in:new_array
            }
          }
      }
    }
}
}
console.log(args);
```

Comment: You have to understand, What type of result I want- `{ category: {name: "Fashion", subCategory: {name: {$in: ["sub", "Hub", "Mub"]}}}}`

Comment: @Savana. That can be done easily. I have edited the fiddle and code here as well have a look